# Yosemite repeatedly tells me to open system preferences to give control to RightZoom but it is checked in system preferences. Whats the matter?

Tags: macos, fullscreen

Whenever I reboot Yosemite (MacBook Pro Early 2011 model), it keeps giving me a bunch of these messages. I have included an image of the [image: screenshot], but then when it opens up System Preferences, RightZoom is already checked, so shouldn't it have access? It is annoying because the new full screen functionality is a bit aggravating

Answer (score 1):

Visit the Privacy tab in the Security prepane. Click the lock icon and enter your password to unlock it. Select RightZoom in the window (don't bother with the check mark at this point) and click the minus (-) underneath the list. Locate the RightZoom application icon wherever you keep it on the computer, and drag it into the list you just deleted it from. You couldn't do that in Mavericks, but it makes the process work better in Yosemite. That way, if the permissions associated with an older version of the package or one that's gotten misplaced on your hard drive, you can set it right. Just be sure that the one you dragged is the one you're using.

Comment: I've run into more of these problems since submitting an answer. You're going to need to perform an in place install of Yosemite, probably. If you'll remove any copies of the Yosemite installer app from your Mac (downloaded to Applications, by default), you can get the latest version of the installer at the App store.